# How to save the state of the fragments in Viewpager after the application is killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-viewpager

I've created a tablayout with Viewpager.The Tablayout has three 3 fragments 'Photo','Video','Docs'. Each fragment has a gridview. In 'Photo' fragment images are loaded to the gridview as thumbnails, In 'Video' fragment videos are loaded to the gridview as thumbnails and so on. When an image is loaded to the Gridview in 'Photo' fragment and after that when the application is killed and opened again, the Gridview has lost its state that is it doesnt have the uploaded images. I know this is happening because the onCreateView is creating the entire UI again. But how to save the State of the Fragment before it gets killed ? Here is the code..

//MainFragment which loads the viewpager

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
static FragmentManager fManager;
static ViewPager viewPager;
View view;
static ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    fManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fManager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    List<Fragment> listOfFragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();

    if (listOfFragments.size() >= 1) {
        for (Fragment fragment : listOfFragments) {
            if (fragment instanceof PhotoFragment) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
           else if (fragment instanceof VideoFragment) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
    }
```

//Photo Fragment

```
    public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment {

private GridView gridView;
private View view;
private Dialog dialog = null;
private ImageView btnCamera;
TextView btnCameradialog, btnGalleryDialog;
private final int CLICK_PHOTO = 1;
private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 2;
private Uri imageUri;
private String path, picturePath, pathlist;
private List<PictureBeans> pictureDisplayList = null;
private ImageAdapter adapter;
private TextView textViewtitle;
private boolean isVisibleToUser = false;


public PhotoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(isVisibleToUser == false) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);

        initUI();
        setListener();


    }
        return view;
}

private void initUI() {

    btnCamera = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fabPicture);

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view_photoFragment);

    pictureDisplayList = new ArrayList<>();
}


private void setListener() {
    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showappwindow();
        }
    });

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            i.putExtra("path", pictureDisplayList.get(position).getPicturePath().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    path = Util.getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), imageUri);
                    Log.v("Uri", "" + imageUri);
                    picturePath = path.toString();
                    Log.e("Picture Path in Frag ", "" + picturePath);
                    PictureBeans bean = new PictureBeans();
                    bean.setPicturePath(picturePath);
                    pictureDisplayList.add(bean);
                    Log.e("List size", "" + pictureDisplayList.size());

                    addToAdapter(pictureDisplayList);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;

        case CLICK_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                try {
                    imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    path = Util.getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), imageUri);
                    Log.e("PATH",""+path);
                    picturePath = path.toString();
                    PictureBeans bean = new PictureBeans();
                    bean.setPicturePath(picturePath);
                    pictureDisplayList.add(bean);

                    addToAdapter(pictureDisplayList);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void addToAdapter(List<PictureBeans> pictureDisplayList) {

    adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), pictureDisplayList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// Pop Up window Code
public void showappwindow() {
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.mydialogstyle);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_photo);

    textViewtitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    textViewtitle.setText("Upload Image");

    btnCameradialog = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCameradialog);
    btnGalleryDialog = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGalleryDialog);
    dialog.show();

    btnCameradialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CLICK_PHOTO);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnGalleryDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
    }
```

//Adapter

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private PhotoFragment photoFragment;
private VideoFragment videoFragment;
private ThreeFragment threeFragment;
private String[] titles = new String[]{"Photo", "Video", "Documents"};

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("request.code", position + 1);
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            photoFragment = new PhotoFragment();
            return photoFragment;

        case 1:
            videoFragment = new VideoFragment();
            return videoFragment;

        case 2:
            threeFragment = new ThreeFragment();
            return threeFragment;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save fragment state in onDestroyView() method，use with Fragment's 
Argument

Comment: can you please tell me how exactly to do that ?